# Ambiguous constructor (java 7)... the only way around this is a Builder pattern, right?

Tags: java

This code compiles fine under Java 6, but when switching to Java 7 results in a compile time error "reference to Foo is ambiguous, both constructor <I,C>Foo(C) in com.company.Foo and constructor <I>Foo(I) in com.company.Foo match"

```
/**
 * Constructor A - acts on a Collection of Iterables
 */
public <I extends Iterable<T>, C extends Collection<I>> Foo(C intervalSeries) {
    initialize(intervalSeries);
}

/**
 * Constructor B - convenience constructor for callers who only have 1 Iterable
 */
public <I extends Iterable<T>> Foo(I intervals) {
    List<I> intervalSeries = newArrayList(1);
    intervalSeries.add(intervals);
    initialize(intervalSeries);
}
```

I can see why (Collections *are* Iterables).  I'm planning on writing a Builder helper class than differentiates the two construction options by providing a differently-named builder method to get around this, but before I do I thought I'd ask: There's no magic wildcard or super incantation that's going to get me out of this, right?

Comment: That code works fine in my IDE. Can you please show the part of the code that calls the constructor and fails?

Comment: Tried under Java 7 without problems. There’s no ambiguity here. One constructor expects a `Collection` the other an `Iterable`. If a class implements both (as with all `Collection`s) the constructor taking a `Collection` will be used as it is more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're overusing generics.

You can simply take a `Collection<I>`, and any subclass of that will be implicitly convertible to that interface.

In fact, you don't need type parameters at all; you can write

```
public Foo(Collection<? extends Iterable<T>> intervalSeries)
public Foo(Iterable<T> intervals)
```

You may also want to change `T` to `? extends T`.

Comment: You're totally right.  I inherited this code an assumed it was "necessarily fancy" but it isn't.  Replacing the current constructors with your suggestion is baller - fixes the problem _and_ improves the code.  Thanks, SLaks

Answer (score 0):

While @SLaks has the best answer, just wanted to add that using factory methods is a possible alternative to a builder, because you can name them.  e.g.  (I may have the generics wrong)

```
public static <I extends Iterable<T>> Foo makeFooFromIterable(I intervals) { ... }

public static <ignore the gererics part about C> Foo makeFooFromCollection(C c) { ... }
```